# Local storage not working issues with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

I am using local storage to allow the user to return to a form after it has been submitted and  amend with previous values persisting.

I succeeded in using the jQuery Storage Api (for set() and get()) but only by writing out long hand for each form element, not ideal. Instead I wanted to push all the form element ids to an array and loop through the array. First part, pushing to the array, works like a charm but the for loop I used is not working.

I intend to use jQuery .each() function but want to understand why my loop is not working first. Thanks.

---

```
(function() {

  var selectArray = [];

  // Getting select ids
  $("select").each(function() {
    selectArray.push($(this).attr("id"));
  });

  // Using Local Storage Api
  var storage = $.localStorage;

  for (var i = 0; i < selectArray.length; i++){

    // Get select element
    $("#" + selectArray[i]).val(storage.get(selectArray[i]));

    // Set select element
    $("#" + selectArray[i]).change(function() {
      var selectValue = $("#" + selectArray[i]).val();
      storage.set(selectArray[i], selectValue);
    });

    // Check loop is working
    console.log(i + ". " + selectArray[i]); 

  }

}());
```

---

Resources:

- jQuery v1.11.0
- [jQuery Storage API](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API)

Comment: $("#" + selectArray[i].change( =>  $("#" + selectArray[i]).change(

Comment: I have not fixed it yet but think I am suffering from function within a loop.

Comment: Also on change event, why are you taking the value from selectArray? Shouldn't that be taken from the select?

Comment: @artm Thanks for the typo. Will have to ponder the select/selectArray. My intention is to use the id, as before, to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the change event handler like this, avoid reference to i. variable i is getting dangled here.

```
$("#" + selectArray[i]).change(function() {

      var selectValue = $(this).val();
      storage.set($(this).attr('id'), selectValue);
});
```

This should work.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hv40x6sa/8/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, we have success!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, inside the change handler function you refer to the loop variable 'i'. When the change handler is actually called, 'i' is dereferenced and always contains the last value: selectArray.length

Comment: Rather put it as a comment.